# Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-identity

I am programming a command line tool (installedApp) that will need access to the Google Sheets of the user. For this I need to get an access token from the user.

I am following these guidelines [OAuth2InstalledApp](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp). So far I managed to get the authorization code by using the `http://localhost` type of redirect_uri. I specified `http://localhost:7373/authorizationCode` as the redirect_uri and I have a local server listening on port 7373.

But when I make the request to get the access token, I get an HTTP 400 Bad request response with a

> redirect_uri_mismatch error

. When I make the request,the redirect_uri is defined as "The redirect URI you obtained from the Developers Console". Which is kind of wrong because when you create an Installed app you don't have the ability to specify a redirect uri (only with web apps). `https://infinit.io/_/i48b2rM`

So my question is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a client ID in the Google Developers Console, two redirect_uris are created for you: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and `http://localhost`. Also you can consider `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto` .The value your application uses determines how the authorization code is returned to your application.  [choose a redirect uri](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi)